# Is there any limit on redirects in StormCrawler?

Tags: web-crawler, apache-storm, stormcrawler

I can see the `_redirTo` tag in Status index of ElasticSearch. A few questions regarding redirection as follows :

1. Any limit on redirection ? so that it should not end in loop of
   redirects ?
2. How many redirects of particular fetched URL ? I can see
       only one redirect in `_redirTo` tag which is immediate one. Cannot get count of redirects if there are two or three redirects of URL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a limit to the depth from the seed, see [MaxDepth URL filter](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/wiki/URLFilters) but not directly on the number of successive redirections.

As you noticed, we track only the URL a given document is redirected to.

If you wanted to control the number of redirs regardless of the distance from the seed, one way would be to extend or modify [MetadataTransfer](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/digitalpebble/stormcrawler/util/MetadataTransfer.java) or handle the redirs within the protocol implementation, the downside being that this will not check whether the target URL has already been fetched.

UPDATE There is a config element called 'redirections.allowed' with a default value of true. I've just pushed a fix for SimpleFetcherBolt as it wasn't handled properly.

Comment: what I noticed by my experiments that StormCrawler does not follow redirected URL means it does not crawl further on that redirected URL. am I correct ? or any flag that I need to make true ? so that It crawls on redirected URL ?

Comment: This is not correct. SC should follow redirections unless one of the URL filters prevents this e.g. depth or other. Please open an issue on GH with a reproducible example if you believe it is not the case and I'll look at it ASAP. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe remove all the URL filters to see if it solves the redir problem.

Comment: I have removed all the URL filters and I am redirecting by meta tag, Still it does not follow that redirected URL.

Comment: Can you please open an issue with the url you are using?  Are you on sc 1.2 or master branch?

Comment: I am on master branch and I was doing on localhost, will put it on server and GH too

Comment: Seen your commit :)